# Does it hold that $|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i|\geq|\sum_{i=1}^n b_i s_i|$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I was trying to prove that a function is convex and I ended up with this problem:

Does it hold that $$|\sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i|\geq|\sum_{i=1}^n b_i s_i|,$$
for every $(s_1,...,s_n)\neq 0$, given that $a_i>|b_i|$, $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The answer is again no.

Comment: @Crostul can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In order to show this, consider the notation $\mathbf{a} = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$, $\mathbf{b} = (b_1, \dots, b_n)$ and $\mathbf{s} = (s_1, \dots, s_n)$. Now, you are asking whether (under some condition on $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$) the following is true for all $\mathbf{s} \in \Bbb{R}^n$
$$|\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{s}| \ge |\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{s}|$$
where $\cdot$ denotes the standard scalar product in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Now, pick any $\mathbf{s}$ which is orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$ and not orthogonal to $\mathbf{b}$ to get a counterexample (such a vector always exists, provided that the two vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ are not collinear).